# File Explorer in java

Tags: file, tabs, directory

I want to write a short application . It must browse the files to seek the folders. If it find a folder, it write on console the name of folder and to into the folder. Next write to console name of txt files included in folder.

My code :

```
import java.io.File;

public class test {
    public static void search(File f) {

        File[] tab = f.listFiles();
        for (File file1 : tab) {
            if (file1.isDirectory()) {
                search(file1);
            } else {
                if (Txt(file1)) {
                    System.out.println("+ " + file1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean Txt(File f) {
        return f.getName().substring(f.getName().length() - 4).equals(".txt");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File f = new File("/home/mati/Pulpit");
            search(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Result of code :

```
+ New Folder
    - aaa.txt
    - abc.txt
    - abf.txt
+ New Folder2
    - abgh.txt
```

My program write only txt files , and i dont know how fix it ...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Something that might help clarify: what are the contents of your folder, and what is the expected output of your program when run in that folder?  As it stands, the output you show appears to be what I would expect.

Comment: It must show the name of the folder and the content of the folder(only txt files )

Comment: As i show it in "result of code"

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: So you mean your output is:

    - aaa.txt
    - abc.txt
    - abf.txt
    - abgh.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: first, to display the folder names, you will need to add a System.out in the branch of the code with the "if (file1.isDirectory())" conditional.  You have a System.out in the "else" portion already, which is why the file names are displaying.

Secondly, though, this will probably not work the way you want it to if you have folders inside of folders.  All folders will display with one level of indentation, and all of the files will display with the other.  But you won't be able to see which folders are nested in the others.